# Non-complete IP addresses and ip2long()

Tags: php

I stubled upon following question:

"What is the output of the following code?"

```
echo long2ip(ip2long("127.0.255"));
```

The correct answer is: "127.0.255.0".

While it seems logical as this behavior is mentioned in the [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) and has even an example in the [german manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ip2long.php), I have my issues reproducing it.

My code produces following outputs:

```
echo ip2long("127.0.255"); // outputs: FALSE
echo long2ip(ip2long("127.0.255")); //outputs: 0.0.0.0
```

The machine I tested this on has following software versions:

- PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 with Suhosin-Patch
- Suhosin Patch 0.9.9.1

None of my colleagues could give me a precise explanation.
The only assumption we have is, that it could be a conflict with the Suhosin-Patch.

If you have an explanation, please let me know.

Comment: I don't run Suhosin, and I have the same output as you - `0.0.0.0`. Version is `PHP 5.4.14`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked up the PHP source code of ip2long.

If inet_pton is available, inet_pton is used. Else inet_addr is used.

inet_pton checks, if the ip has the format ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd else it returns 0.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html

if inet_addr is used, then missing parts of the ip are filled up with 0.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP manual also states (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php):

> Changelog
>
> Version    Description
>
> 5.2.10   Prior to this version, ip2long() would sometimes return a valid number even if passed an value which was not an (IPv4) Internet Protocol dotted address.

So, as you are using a newer version than 5.2.9 and it doesn't work anymore.

**Update:** But it will work maybe on some systems as the inet_addr C function on which relies the ip2long function is not a part of the C standard: every system may have its own implementation of it. Some of these implementations have fallback modes for invalid IP addresses. You shouldn't rely on this as the most unix derivatives don't have such a fallback.

Comment: Yes, I read this. But the discription still mentiones: "ip2long() will also work with non-complete IP addresses."

Comment: @tobyte This is a system dependent implementation; don't rely on this.

Comment: It seems so. But then the question do not have a particular answer and the one in my learning material is wrong.

Comment: @tobyte In any unix I just have tested this, it doesn't work... maybe it'll work on windows

Comment: I can confirm this. I have tested it on debian, centos an osx.

Comment: Hmm inet_addr seems to be in the standard C library see: http://publibn.boulder.ibm.com/doc_link/en_US/a_doc_lib/libs/commtrf2/inet_addr.htm

Comment: @tobyte the standard C library are here the preinstalled headers by default. But it isn't by the C standard. The header is located in 
/usr/include/arpa/inet.h.

Comment: @tobyte THIS are the standard C header files: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ip2long` for IP validation, I suggest using `filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP` instead.

[PHP filter validation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)

Comment: ip2long for validation works too, you only have to check against !== false... (although it isn't the recommended way)

Comment: I dont actually want to use this code for validation, it was only a question in my learning material.

Comment: @bwoebi except that prior to 5.2.10 ip2long could validate an invalid IP, as you showed in your answer - `false === ip2long('1.2.3')` would validate as a correct IP before 5.2.10